# Windows 8.1 store app https local server using Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket

Tags: sockets, webview, https, windows-store-apps, windows-networking

I'm working on a Windows8.1 Store app using JavaScript.

As per the requirement we are serving the html files with the help of a *http* local server which uses Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket.Listener.

[Here](http://www.dzhang.com/blog/2012/09/18/a-simple-in-process-http-server-for-windows-8-metro-apps) is the example of the *http* server I'm using and its working fine for *http* requests.

If I change the source to *https* the local server receives request, but the InputStream will be encrypted.

Is there way to decrypt and get the InputStream? May be by using any SSL certificates.

The problem is x-ms-webview in windows 8.1 app require **https** source to perform script notification i.e MSWebViewScriptNotify event.

As we are not using any external website to make it https, how to make this local server to accept https requests and serve the files.

Comment: Unfortunately, **Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener** does not support SSL/TLS out of the box as **Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket** does. You will need to  find a third-party library, maybe [OpenSSL.NET](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/10/13/winsock-and-more-open-source-for-your-windows-store-apps/)?

Comment: Thanks @kiewic, fortunately we are able to serve the files with the help of [navigateToLocalStreamUri](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn301843.aspx) and the scriptnotify is working fine here.